# Shopware6 Cart API

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

I am building an Angular integration in Shopware 6, the whole store relies on the storefront theme, but the JS application can add products via the store-api as well. Now how can I add the item to the storefront cart?
I post the data to the /store-api/checkout/cart/line-item API and even with context-token which I fetched from the /store-api/context API before, it doesn’t work. Is there any way I can add items to the storefront cart with the current session via the API? Or maybe I can get the current context output somewhere to then take the token and update the current cart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the basic steps right, so it's not really easy to answer without full context.

1. Retrieve the context token from the `token` property of the response body after a request to `GET /store-api/context`
2. Request `POST /store-api/checkout/cart/line-item` with the context token set as the header `sw-context-token` and a valid payload as the request body. A minimal payload would look like this:

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      // the id of the product entity
      "referencedId": "801419a0c21645a8a71f70049422a056",
      "type": "product"
    }
  ]
}
```

3. If all went well it should return the data for the updated cart in the response body
4. You can verify that the cart persisted by requesting `GET /store-api/checkout/cart` with the same `sw-context-token`

I just went through these steps and that works. Keep in mind that the product must also be available for the sales channel you get the context token for, which in turn is determined by the `sw-access-key` header you use for authorization across all these requests.

Comment: Yes, that is clear as far as it goes. But I want to update the current shopping cart in the storefront theme via api. So the shopping cart that the customer sees when he calls the store (It's not an api based theme, the regular storefront). The request from the storefront theme works with the session, if I see that correctly? But how can I add an item to this shopping cart via api. That I then click on "show cart" and there are then my articles?

Comment: You should use the existing storefront controller then. There the context token is resolved from the session, that is correct. In that case you can just  send an ajax request to `https://example.tld/checkout/line-item/add`. See the comments in controller class for [an example of a payload](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Storefront/Controller/CartLineItemController.php#L208): As with the store-api, the key should be the `id` of the product and the type should be `product`.